# How can't subscribe to Firestore from Google Sheets with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Google sheet page with a 5 records, this page go to google firestore through gogoole appscript.Also I have a trigger onEdit. I need to cicle the data beacause when I edit sheets, the data is duplicate on firestore. Here the code of App Script .

```
`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);

   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;



   // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     var data = {}

     data.nomeProdotto= sourceData[i][0],
     data.foto= sourceData[i][1],
     data.costo= sourceData[i][2],
     data.quantità= sourceData[i][3],
     data.id=sourceData[i][4]
      firestore.createDocument("shopping-cart",data);

     }

   }


function onEdit(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
  Browser.msgBox("la riga modificata è la " + e.range.getRow());
}
`
```

Comment: So is your main issue that basically every time you update a cell all the data is uploaded again to firestore, am I right ? Is your top function a normal funciton or is it also another ```onEdit()``` function?

Comment: Yes, you are right. On my top I have a firestore function for write the data on firestore

Comment: I cannot see right now how is your data uploaded again after you edit your sheet as your ```firestore.createDocument``` is NOT in the ```onEdit()``` function. **Could you please share an example spreadsheet (with no sensitive data) or the full script** so that I can visualise better what is going on and why is this happening? Also, shouldn't you have ```var data = {}``` before the ```for``` loop? And shouldn't you have ```firestore.createDocument``` outside of the ```for``` loop and after it? **Give it a try to these suggestions just in case that was the issue**. Thanks !!